# SwiftUI DatePicker displaying months in English only?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have set the iOS simulator to be in Spanish and region to Argentina. SwiftUI's DatePicker correctly shows the components' order as per the locale (day, month, year) but the month names are in English.
How can it be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

Date pickers handle their own internationalization, so in the Attributes Inspector you should be able to specify the locale. Give that a shot and let us know if it works.

Comment: I'm on Mojave, can't install Catalina yet. Not seeing a way to open attributes inspector for the DatePicker. I can't either find a way to set its locale in code, can you tell me what the code would look like?

Comment: You should be able to access the attributes inspector  regardless of XCode version. If you select the date picker in your storyboard file and look at the top right of the left panel (if it is hidden un-hide it).

Comment: Nope, this is SwiftUI, there's no storyboard.

Comment: Oh sorry then you should be able to access it programmatically using the 'locale' property